# Nginx, как сделать редирект на каноничное имя при множестве доменов?

Tags: nginx

Есть несколько доменов, что слушает nginx:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_name www.example.ru;
    server_name www.example.org;
}
```

Есть редирект на каноничное имя.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    server_name example.ru;
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Но как сохранять домен первого уровня в редиректе.

Например, сейчас, перейдя на любой из доменов (example.com, example.ru, example.org) попадаешь на [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

А необходимо чтобы домен первого уровня брался из url, например:

- example.com - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- example.org - [www.example.org](http://www.example.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    server_name example.ru;
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```